# Symfony 3 merge under global domain

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, routes, controllers

I have domains webpage.com, webpage.ee, webpage.eu and I would like to merge them under the same domain with webpage.com/ee or webpage.com/eu.

What is the best/easiest way to achive this? All the domains currently use the same codebase.

Do I have to change all the routes and links manually or is there a better way?

Comment: You can do that in your web server (nginx, apache). There's no need to change all routes

Comment: I use nginx, could you show me an example ?

Comment: see `proxy_pass` in the nginx config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com
    location /en {
        add_header X-Lang en
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in Symfony you probably need a request listener to read the language header and set the locale or whatever you may be interested in.

You could also use more advanced techniques like regular expressions to match the locations, and set the header.

Comment: with that solution, the links will still be webpage.com/whatever, instead of webpage.com/ee/whatever

Comment: How? Can you share your nginx config? Do you have something in Symfony hardcoding the app URL?

Comment: the only difference is that I set fastcgi_param in the conf to set my language, so for webpage.ee I set EE as lang.

Comment: Then it should work... You're setting the location to /en (or whatever). Are you sure you're not using location /? If you're worried about accessing directly /, you can set a redirect on Nginx itself